# Get value for a match from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with tuples. I am trying to find value for a match in tuple.
For example, if `M` is in `a`, then it should return `10`. Can someone help me figuring out what I am missing here?

```
>>> c
'M'
>>> a
[[('N', '64')], [('W', '1024')], [('M', '10')], [('C', '2')], [('RA', '8')]]

>>> c in a
False

>>> a[2][0][0]
'M'

>>> [item for item in a if a[item][0][0] == c]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Comment: What should it return if the list was `[[('X', '1')], [('M', '2')], [('M', '3')]`?

Comment: You're already iterating over your `a` so its indices are in `item`. Lose the `a[item]` part and use `item` only.

Comment: you are using 'item'(list) as list indice, this is wrong

Comment: Kevin, it won't have repeated entries.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why each tuple are wrapped in a list ? This is more than just a _list with tuples_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert your list to a dictionary

```
d = dict(map(lambda x: x[0], a))
```

and use simple lookup:

```
>>> d['M']
10
```

Answer (score 1):

That last bit should be:

```
[item for item in a if item[0][0] == c]
```

This is because `item` already refers to the highest-level list in `a`, so you do not need the `a[item]`.

Comment: I posted this before I saw the comment on the question by @zwer, which recommended this.